# Why is Jquery Datatables sending a negative max int after my Api Call?

Tags: datatables

The code:

```js
 $(function () {
    $('#project').dataTable({
        //"aLengthMenu": [[2, 5, 10, -1], ["Two", "Five", "Ten", "All"]],
        'ajax': {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": 'api/Project/GetAll/',
            //"data": { "": "" },
            "dataSrc":""
        },
        'columns': [
        //Stuff
    });
});
```

What I should be calling:

```
 http://localhost:50912/api/Project/GetAll/
```

This returns the data I expect

What I am actually calling:

```
 http://localhost:50912/Project/api/Project/GetAll/?_=1425525348729
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a cache parameter [http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/15542/the-underscore-parameter](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/15542/the-underscore-parameter)

Comment: as @markpsmith mentions, it is the basic jQuery non-caching param.  jQuery adds `_={timestamp}` to the GET parameters. You will see that in any other jQuery ajax call that have `cache : false`.